# A variation on the Gambler’s Ruin Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Consider a gambler who starts with an initial fortune of \$10 and then
>   on each successive gamble either wins **\$2** or loses \$1 independent
>   of the past with probabilities 0.3 and 0.7 respectively. The gambles
>   would stop when the gambler going broke or when he reaching \$20.
>
> What is his chance of going broke?

I can deal with the case that each successive gamble either wins *\$1* or loses \$1,
but I have no idea how to derive the probability of this problem.

Comment: How long / how many times do we repeat the gambles? Infinitely many times?

Comment: I have just edited the question, thank you.

Comment: This is an [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a Markov chain with states
$0,1,2,3,\dots,18,19,20$,
where $20$ stays for "over $20$".
The states $0$ and $20$ are final. All other states are intermediate. We start in $10$.
Let
$$x_k$$
be the probabilitiy that starting in the state $k$ we reach $20$ before $0$.

We denote by $p=0,3$ the win probability, and by $q=1-p=0.7$ the losing probability in each single game.
The question wants $x_{10}$.

Using the Markov property, we have the following system of equations (as also in the case $p=q=0.5$):
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_0 &= 0\ ,\\
x_1 &= px_3+qx_0\ ,\\
x_2 &= px_4+qx_1\ ,\\
x_3 &= px_5+qx_2\ ,\\
\vdots\qquad&\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\\
x_k &= px_{k+2}+qx_{k-1}\ ,\\
\vdots\qquad&\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\vdots\qquad\\
x_{17} &= px_{19}+qx_{16}\ ,\\
x_{18} &= px_{20}+qx_{17}\ ,\\
x_{19} &= px_{20}+qx_{18}\ ,\\
x_{20} &= 1\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
We can solve this system with the computer (in the given century, this is best solving the typing problem for the solution):

```
p, q = 3/10, 7/10 
v = var( ','.join( [ 'x%s'%k for k in [0..20] ] ) )

equations = [ v[ 0] == 0,
              v[19] == p*v[20]+q*v[18],
              v[20] == 1, ]
for k in [1..18]:
    equations.append( v[k] == p*v[k+2] + q * v[k-1] )
solutions = solve( equations, v )[0]
solutions
```

Results:

```
sage: solutions
[x0 == 0,
 x1 == (97997418836757/6340325131549730),
 x2 == (227159167631733/6974357644704703),
 x3 == (32665806278919/634032513154973),
 x4 == (5056705170914337/69743576447047030),
 x5 == (667708172419653/6974357644704703),
 x6 == (847146029145858/6974357644704703),
 x7 == (10457960348521647/69743576447047030),
 x8 == (1265834361507003/6974357644704703),
 x9 == (1509312714833547/6974357644704703),
 x10 == (1617506476092387/6340325131549730),
 x11 == (188857170235953/634032513154973),
 x12 == (2409127411060476/6974357644704703),
 x13 == (2521057230316197/6340325131549730),
 x14 == (3183090667478793/6974357644704703),
 x15 == (3622579218684945/6974357644704703),
 x16 == (41395886671177377/69743576447047030),
 x17 == (4648052504832633/6974357644704703),
 x18 == (5345944046794254/6974357644704703),
 x19 == (58344681261673887/69743576447047030),
 x20 == 1]
sage:
```

So the **win** (not the ruin) probability is

```
sage: (1617506476092387/6340325131549730).n()
0.255114121520930
```

The denominators are related to the determinant of the system matrix, which is...

```
R.<p,q> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
A = matrix( R, 21, 21 )
A[0,0] = 1

for k in [1..18]:
    A[k,k-1], A[k,k], A[k,k+2] = -q, 1, -p

A[19,18], A[19,19], A[19,20] = -q, 1, -p
A[20,20] = 1

print "The matrix for the system is:"
print A
print "\nThe determinant of A(p,q) is:", A.det().factor()
print "\nThe determinant of A(0.3, 0.7) is:", A.det()(3/10, 7/10)
```

This gives:

```
The matrix for the system is:
[ 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[-q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1  0 -p]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -q  1 -p]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]

The determinant of A(p,q) is: 7*p^6*q^12 - 126*p^5*q^10 + 330*p^4*q^8 - 286*p^3*q^6 + 105*p^2*q^4 - 17*p*q^2 + 1

The determinant of A(0.3, 0.7) is: 6974357644704703/1000000000000000000
```

I printed also the inverse, this convinced me to not search for a "human solution"...

**Moral:**

- The gambler wins the $20$ or $21$ dollars and stops with probability
  $$\frac{1617506476092387}{6340325131549730}
  \approx
  0.255114121520930\dots\ .
  $$
- The gambler is ruined and stops with complementary probability
  $$
  \frac{4722818655457343}{6340325131549730}
  \approx 0.744885878479070\dots\ .
  $$

Answer (score 3):

You can model this as an absorbing Markov chain with 22 states, i.e. bankrolls from 0 to 21 dollars, inclusive.  There are three absorbing states, 0, 20, and 21.  (We need 21 because he might win 2 dollars in state 19.)  The initial state is 10 with probability 1.  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) explains how to do the relevant calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of going broke is $1$ because the expectation per round is negative.

*Answer to the edited question:*

This can be handled by the same approach as the $\pm\$1$ case. Let $p_k$ be the probability of going broke with $k$ dollars. Then

$$p_k=0.3p_{k+2}+0.7p_{k-1}\;,$$

and the *ansatz* $p_k=\lambda^k$ yields the characteristic equation

$$
0.3\lambda^3-\lambda+0.7=0\;.
$$

One root is $\lambda=1$, and factoring this out yields $(\lambda-1)(0.3\lambda^2+0.3\lambda-0.7)=0$, so the other two roots are $\lambda=-\frac12\pm\sqrt{\frac{31}{12}}$. The general solution is a linear combination of these three solutions, and the three coefficients are determined by the three conditions $p_0=1$, $p_{20}=0$ and $p_{21}=0$.

Comment: I have just edited the question, thank you.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain the downvote?